# SQL Create Record Vertically

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, pivot, pivot-table

How do I query in SQL from this:

| Name | Year1 | Year2 | Year 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jack | 400 | 500 | 600 |

To this :

| Name | YearX |
| --- | --- |
| Jack | 400 |
| Jack | 500 |
| Jack | 600 |

Comment: Noted, thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for an unpivot operation.  One simple approach uses `UNION ALL`:

```sql
SELECT Name, Year1 AS YearX, 1 AS position FROM yourTable UNION ALL
SELECT Name, Year2, 2 FROM yourTable UNION ALL
SELECT Name, Year3, 3 FROM yourTable
ORDER BY position;
```

Comment: Hi Tim,

Thank you for your assistance. I would like to understand what is the position for?

Comment: The result of a `UNION` or `UNION ALL` query is, similar to the tables it queries, just another unordered set of records.  If you want to guarantee the order you seem to expect in your output, you need a computed column for that.  So, I add position numbers to each part of the union query and then order using that position.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, I strongly recommend using `APPLY` for unpivoting:

```
select t.name, v.yearx
from t cross apply
     (values (year1, 1), (year2, 2), (year3, 3)
     ) v(yearx, which);
```

Note you can select the second column `which` if you want the original column.

Why do I recommend this over `union all`?  Of course, it is shorter to write.

More importantly, it refers to the original table only once, so the table is scanned only once.  This is a marginal performance gain on a table.  It can be significant if the "table" is really a view or CTE.